# Why doesn't this for loop print the same integer during each iteration?

Tags: python

In the following code snippet , I am confused as to why the first element of a list can be used to iterate another list. Can someone please explain why this does not just print the integer 0 six times?

```
idx = [0,0,0]

junk = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6]

for idx[0] in junk:

    print(idx[0])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code looks weird. You store the looping number into `idx[0]` that way - you can see that by printing it:

```
idx = [0,0,0]

junk = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6]

for idx[0] in junk:
    print(idx[0], idx)
```

to get

```
1 [1, 0, 0]
2 [2, 0, 0]
3 [3, 0, 0]
4 [4, 0, 0]
5 [5, 0, 0]
6 [6, 0, 0]
```

So you are activly changing the value of `idx[0]` on each iteration - how many iterations are done is ruled by `junk`'s values.

You can create a "creative/inefficient" list-copy by that:

```
junk = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6]
idx = [0] * len(junk)
for i,idx[i] in enumerate(junk): 
    pass
```

although I have no clue whatfor one would need that :D

Comment: Haha... “creative” code == fails code review.

Comment: @Seth absolutely!

Answer (score 0):

Because the for-loop assigns to the loop variable (`idx[0]` in your case). And that is allowed in your example.

You have ended up modifying the `idx` array by doing this:

```
idx = [0,0,0]

junk = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6]

for idx[0] in junk:

    print(idx[0])

print(idx)
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
[6, 0, 0]  # idx[0] is 6, the last value assigned to it by the for-loop
```

Answer (score 0):

`for idx[0] in junk:` changes the `idx[0]` in each iteration. Add `print(idx)` to see that. Use `for i in junk:` to loop over junk.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is iterator protocol. Everytime you iterate through `junk` it will set the idx[0] to next value. 
You might think it behaves like the code below;

```
idx = [0, 0, 0]
junk = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

junk = iter(junk)
idx[0] = next(junk)
idx[0] = next(junk)
idx[0] = next(junk)
idx[0] = next(junk)
idx[0] = next(junk)
idx[0] = next(junk)
print(idx[0])
```